# Trying to use autoResize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this simple textarea. When it's not selected, I want it to look like a finished product(i.e. the sides tapered to the text). I also want to let the user change the width. How can I use the autoresize plugin to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pathway Builder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <textarea class="text_field_not_selected"></textarea>

    <script src="jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="selectors.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript/jQuery

```
$('textarea').bind('focusin blur', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('text_field_not_selected');
});
$('textarea').autoResize();
```

css

```
body {
    display: block;
}

textarea:focus {
    outline:  none;
    text-align: center;
}

.text_field_not_selected {
    text-align: center;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #444;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first part, you could use something like

```
border-style: none;
```

and for the second part you can just click and drag the bottom right corner of the text box and resize it

Comment: I don't want the user to be able to control the size. I know I kinda said the opposite in the header, but what I'm really going for is to autoresize the height:width ratio to about 2:3.